# Detecting language by string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some tool to detect the language of the string for javascript. I need to detect the language for sending the "Locale" parameter to server. Is there is some library doing this thing on client side?

Comment: You can have a look at http://i18next.com.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't exist yet. Feel free to make a language processing library in Javascript, a lot of people would like it!

Comment: @user2952238 I think the author meant detecting the language of a string input by a user, not displaying translated text.

Comment: unfortunately, words are not unique to one language

Comment: sure, I'm not talking about 100% success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has an API you can use for this:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?csw=1#search/language.detections.list/m/translate/v2/language.detections.list

For example, you request:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/detect?q=I'm+looking+for+some+tool+to+detect+the+language+of+the+string+for+javascript.&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

You receive:

```
200 OK

{
 "data": {
  "detections": [
   [
    {
     "language": "en",
     "isReliable": false,
     "confidence": 0.80974126
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: That's damn awesome!